# Synchronous Task "Queues" with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, message-queue

I have a deployed & functioning Django application that uses celery workers to execute background tasks. We are looking at the possibility of switching to AWS Lambda for running our background tasks instead to help save on costs, but are unsure how we would structure our project.

**Current Structure**

The app currently consists of an Elastic Beanstalk app with an EC2 instance running the web server and Celery Beat (for some regularly-scheduled tasks), and a separate EC2 Celery worker instance that executes the tasks. In the app's current configuration, I am using Celery with Amazon's SQS to trigger functions executed by the worker instance.

Key to our application is that we may receive several items to be queued up at once. Multiple queue items can execute at the same time, but only one item *from each user* can execute concurrently. We have accomplished this by using named queues for each user and configuring Celery to only run one task from any given queue at a time.

**Questions / Desired Structure**

We would like to transition to using AWS lambda functions to execute our background tasks, because we have significant gaps in application usage (we typically get tasks in large groups) and this can save on costs. Our biggest question is whether there is a way to "categorize" lambda invocations such that we can have multiple functions executing at once, but only one executing from each category. Lambda seems to have features for managing concurrency, but only per-function and not with any equivalent to the multiple queues that we are using currently.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you may want to leverage [AWS SQS fifo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-understanding-logic.html) queues.

You can set your MessageGroupId to your user's Ids, that way you will be able to process Users' messages in parallel.

Per the documentation:

> Receiving messages
> You can't request to receive messages with a specific message group ID.

You won't be able to filter by user ID.

> When receiving messages from a FIFO queue with multiple message group IDs, Amazon SQS first attempts to return as many messages with the same message group ID as possible. This allows other consumers to process messages with a different message group ID. When you receive a message with a message group ID, no more messages for the same message group ID are returned unless you delete the message or it becomes visible.

This explains that SQS Fifo is processing messages by messageGroupID. That means that until you didn't process and delete messages with the same messageGroupId from the queue (it's automatically done by AWS lambda trigger on lambda success), it won't process the others.

On the other hand, it can process other messages with different messageGroupId.

> Messages that belong to the same message group are always processed one by one, in a strict order relative to the message group (however, messages that belong to different message groups might be processed out of order).

I recommend you try and do a mini load-test with Messages in the to simulate the behavior you expect and see if it feat your needs!

You can do a simple SQS FIFO that triggers a lambda with maximum concurrency allowed (1000 for standard accounts).
Then you push messages using a script, with different messageGroupIds, and random ordering. And see how is it processed.

This won't cost so much since it's serverless and will save you a lot of time and issues in the future. (probably money too).